# how Does TreeSet sort numbers as Strings for example "123","234";

Tags: sorting, treeset

This is my code for a sample experiment

```
TreeSet ts = new TreeSet();     
ts.add("A");
ts.add("Z");
ts.add("C");
ts.add("F");
ts.add("1");
ts.add("8");
ts.add("10000");
ts.add("999");

System.out.println(ts);
```

Output:

```
[1, 10000, 8, 999, A, C, F, Z]
```

How are the objects sorted, and on what basis?

Thank you

Comment: First you should learn about [tree data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) and how [Red-black trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) work

Answer (score 1):

Treeset sort the number as string in lexicographical order. 
Example :
if you insert numbers in following order:

```
 [ 12 , 2434 , 23 , 1 , 654 , 222 , 56 , 100000 ]
```

Then the output will be:

```
[ 1 , 100000 , 12 , 222 , 23 , 2434 , 56 , 654 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html):

> The elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at set creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) is a description of the `Comparable` interface that is used to determine an object's ordering.